# Parallel Threads to check input in realtime

Tags: java, multithreading

I am making a very simple example of a searchbar, where I want to provide suggestions for what the user might search in real time (just like Google).

So my plan is to use 2 different threads, 1 for running the frame and one that runs the method to check the input of the user and adapt the suggestions.

But I'm having logical troubles here, because I need to use the same object in both runnables, and obviously this can't work:

```
     Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Suchfenster inst = new Suchfenster();
        }
      };

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //check(inst);   -> I need to use the created frame here
        }
     };
```

The only other idea I'd have would be:

```
    Suchfenster inst;
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            inst = new Suchfenster();
        }
    };
```

Which of course doesn't work too.

What would be the right way to do it?

Comment: Does this happen in Swing? In that case, use an event listener. When you type something, a background thread can search for stuff and display them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the `inst = new Suchfenster()` outside the runnable? this way you can share it between the two runnables...
One more thing - remember that u need a thread safe instance if u want to use the same instance in both of the threads...

Comment: Well I did declare the `inst = new Suchfenster()` outside, but now the frame is not IN the thread, but I need two parallel threads for my idea to work

Comment: I don't really understand what u'r saying.. maybe if u could post your code here I'll be more helpful...?

Comment: It's ok, I'll just try what that other guy suggested, thanks for your time though